# Trying to create a custom column for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm trying to create a custom column for my custom post type and I'm having no luck. Below is the code I'm using, I have a similar code that pulls the featured thumbnail and that works for all post types, but this column will only show up on the custom post type. Any help would be appreciated.

```
add_filter("manage_Featured_columns", "edit_Featured_columns" );
add_action("manage_Featured_column", "custom_Featured_columns");
function custom_Featured_columns($Featured_column) {
    global $post;
    switch ($Featured_column) {
        case "redirect_url":
                if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'redirect_url', true) !='') {
                    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'redirect_url', true);
                } else { echo '-'; }

} }
```

That is the code I have so far, but it's not showing up on the Featured custom post type. The name I'm using in my custom post type is: register_post_type( 'Featured',

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a couple of things

1. hook for registering custom column is `manage_edit-{$post_type}_columns` thus you have to use `manage_edit-Featured_columns` on line one (instead of yours manage_Featured_columns ).
2. hook for getting custom column content is `manage_{$post_type}_posts_custom_column` thus you should use this code in second add_action call: `manage_Featured_posts_custom_column`
3. You have to add define columns which are about to appear in edit_Featured_columns function (first add_action call).

This way:

```
function edit_Featured_columns( $columns ) {
        return array(
            'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
            'title' => __( 'Title' ),
            'redirect_url' => __( 'Redirect url' ),
            'date' => __( 'Date' )
        );
    }
```

That's all. Your custom_Featured_columns function seems to be ok.

Here's a good tutorial on this topic: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/06/27/custom-columns-for-custom-post-types